# Recursive function taking too long to run when value of "n" is large

Tags: java, recursion, biginteger

I am trying to get the value for a `n`-th series. such that `f(n)=2014*f(n-1) + 69*f(n-2)` for `(n>2)` and `f(n)=1` for `n<=2`. I am using `BigInteger` as it is my requirement. While running code for smaller values I am getting answer. When `n` exceeds such as 123 I am not getting the result. Any modification in code or way to shrink run the time??

```
public class test {
    public static BigInteger FindSumDigit (BigInteger number) {
         BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
         BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");
         BigInteger result, zero = new BigInteger("0");
         BigInteger a = new BigInteger("2014");
         BigInteger b = new BigInteger("69");
         if(number.equals(one))
             return one;
         else if (number.equals(two))
             return one;
         else
             return a.multiply(FindSumDigit(number.subtract(one))).add(b.multiply(FindSumDigit(number.subtract(two)))); //finding the n-th element

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = s.nextInt();
        BigInteger q[] = new BigInteger[N];
        if(1 <= N && N < 10)
            for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                BigInteger n = s.nextBigInteger();
                BigInteger o = FindSumDigit(n);
                System.out.println(o);
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: In this case, don't use recursion, because you double the calls everytime you get one step in depth further. Use an iterative approach instead.

Comment: in addition to doing it iteratively, consider using primitive ints where possible. Allocating a lot of BigIntegers (or any object) is going to slow things down. Also use BigInteger.ZERO and BigInteger.ONE instead of allocating them yourself.

Comment: @ Unihedron - Thanks for ur feedback. As mentioned in my description  i am getting the number of testcases (N) in first line following N lines containing the value n.for each value of n i want to find the nth element in the series of f(n) metioned above.

Comment: I don't know which problem is more classic for interviews nowadays - this or FizzBuzz. This is *almost* word-to-word as "Calculate n-th Fibonacci" and has all the usual problems a novice programmer might make.

Comment: How about memoizing f(n)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recursive function below is an example of a linear recurrence or a "Fibonacci like sequence."

```
f(n)=2014*f(n-1) + 69*f(n-2) for (n>2)
```

Although this function is naturally defined recursively, to translate this mathematical definition directly into a program is a classic example of when **NOT** to use recursion. In fact, the number of function calls the computer needs to make for a given input, n, is itself a Fibonacci sequence! Since the nth fibonacci number is approximately ((1 + sqrt(5))/2 )^n, the number of function calls grows exponentially. For small values of n, this won't matter. But after a certain point the computer will either lock up or throw a StackOverflow Exception.

Here is a non-recursive solution that avoids this problem:

```
static BigInteger a = new BigInteger("2014");
static BigInteger b = new BigInteger("69");   

public static BigInteger computeNthTerm(int n) {
   BigInteger prev1 = new BigInteger("1");
   BigInteger prev2 = new BigInteger("1");
   BigInteger nth = new BigInteger("1");
   for(int k=2; k<n; k++) {
      nth = prev2.multiply(a).add( prev1.multiply(b) );
      prev1 = prev2;
      prev2 = nth;
   }
   return nth;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a second order linear recurrence and has a closed form solution, have a look here for example http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearRecurrenceEquation.html

Comment: While it's great to see a good mathematical solution to the question, this uses roots (and hence potentially irrational numbers) in the calculations, and is very likely to give precision and rounding errors. It also has a "to the power of n" operator in it's closed form, which opens a whole new can of worms, while an iterative solution will have just n steps with arbitrary precision.